# Simple SIP call receiver and recorder

Tags: linux, sip, voip, recorder

Any linux library or docker container for:

1. receiving simultaneous voip SIP calls, and for each call,
2. recording the incoming audio stream to a distinct file,
3. having silence as outgoing audio stream.

Essentially, a simple sip call receiver and recorder, accepting simultaneous calls, and playing silence.

Drachtio did not work out-of-the-box. Is there an easier alternative? Maybe, a very simple softphone would be fine to start with? A Gstreamer pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with c# and can install `dotnet` on your Linux machine then my [library](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery) can do that. Here's a single call [example](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/tree/master/examples/SIPExamples/RecordIncomingCall) of recording an incoming call. It will need to be enhanced if you want to co-ordinate multiple calls.